# Storm terminating before input document is fully parsed (using streamparse)

Tags: python, stream, apache-storm

I am using Parse.ly/streamparse (https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse) to write a storm topology that contains a single spout that emits tuples from a json document to be parsed for specified fields and keep a running total of the number of instances in each of the specified fields, as well as the ten most common occurences of each. It works fine, except the process is killed before it is finished reading the input json. I'm still really new to this, so my first approach was to simply check every file in my storm topology for any code that seems like it may be responsible for terminating the process early, but I found nothing of the sort. Google has been failing me as well.

Some files I feel may be relevant (there are too many in the topology for me to practically post)

Spout:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

import itertools
import json
from streamparse.spout import Spout

class actor_data(Spout):

    records = []
    name = "/Users/randallbanks/Virtualenvs/test/first_harvest_topology/data/405labs/reports/drive/drive_2014-01-01_to_2015-02-17.macie.json"


    def initialize(self, stormconf, context):
        # load our json file into a python dictionary 
        with open(self.name) as data_file:
            for line in data_file:
                self.records.append(json.loads(line.strip()))


    def next_tuple(self):
        if len(self.records) > 0:
            self.emit([self.records.pop()])
```

topology.clj:

```
(ns first_harvest_topology
  (:use     [streamparse.specs])
  (:gen-class))

(defn first_harvest_topology [options]
   [
    ;; spout configuration
    {"actor-data" (python-spout-spec
          options
          "spouts.actorData.actor_data"
          ["actor_data"]
          )
    }
    ;; bolt configurations
    {"appID-Bolt" (python-bolt-spec
          options
          {"actor-data" :shuffle}
          "bolts.getAppID_Bolt.getAppID"
          ["appID" "user" "docTitle" "eventDesc"]
          )

    "appCount-Bolt" (python-bolt-spec
          options
          {"appID-Bolt" :shuffle}
          "bolts.appCount_Bolt.appCount"
          ["most_common_app" "most_common_user" "most_common_docTitle" "most_common_eventDesc"]
          )

    "mostCommon-Bolt" (python-bolt-spec
         options
         {"appCount-Bolt" :shuffle}
         "bolts.tenMostCommon_Bolt.mostCommon"
         [];does not emit any fields
         )
    }
  ]
)
```

Output with all app counts/etc omitted:

```
    4593 [Thread-22-mostCommon-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess - Storm multilang serializer: backtype.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer
4611 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor __system:[-1 -1]
4615 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks __system:[-1 -1]
4631 [Thread-24-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt __system:(-1)
4631 [Thread-24-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt __system:(-1)
4632 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor __system:[-1 -1]
4636 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Launching receive-thread for 11584c17-a7af-45a4-a2b3-d6285d13a730:1024
4643 [Thread-25-worker-receiver-thread-0] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Starting receive-thread: [stormId: first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, port: 1024, thread-id: 0 ]
4648 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker has topology config {"storm.id" "first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390", "dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "storm.messaging.netty.flush.check.interval.ms" 10, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "/var/folders/4x/pbrwf_8106j6spvvdp8mwm8m0000gn/T//b7c396ef-27b4-455b-9387-1e8f91c24ca4", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" 2, "streamparse.log.path" "/Users/randallbanks/Virtualenvs/test/first_harvest_topology/logs", "topology.kryo.decorators" (), "topology.name" "first_harvest_topology", "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker.childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size" 1048576, "topology.max.spout.pending" 5000, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" (1024 1025 1026), "topology.debug" false, "nimbus.task.launch.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.kryo.register" nil, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 60, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 2, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "topology.multilang.serializer" "backtype.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "topology.worker.receiver.thread.count" 1, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m", "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.transfer.batch.size" 262144, "streamparse.log.level" "debug"}
4658 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker 19989cf7-f5b8-4e88-8aef-7a752d948057 for storm first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390 on 11584c17-a7af-45a4-a2b3-d6285d13a730:1024 has finished loading
4978 [Thread-8-actor-data] INFO  backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout - Launched subprocess with pid 9310
4978 [Thread-8-actor-data] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Opened spout actor-data:(3)
4980 [Thread-8-actor-data] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Activating spout actor-data:(3)
4998 [Thread-12-appID-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt - Launched subprocess with pid 9311
5000 [Thread-12-appID-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt appID-Bolt:(5)
5048 [Thread-18-appCount-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt - Launched subprocess with pid 9312
5049 [Thread-18-appCount-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt appCount-Bolt:(4)
5081 [Thread-22-mostCommon-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt - Launched subprocess with pid 9313
5082 [Thread-22-mostCommon-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt mostCommon-Bolt:(6)
8093 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Shutting down master
8099 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Shut down master
8104 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shutting down 11584c17-a7af-45a4-a2b3-d6285d13a730:19989cf7-f5b8-4e88-8aef-7a752d948057
8104 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.process-simulator - Killing process 665fc2db-3752-4d6d-9c56-d48cc09f9636
8104 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down worker first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390 11584c17-a7af-45a4-a2b3-d6285d13a730 1024
8105 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down receive thread
8105 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Shutting down receiving-thread: [first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1024]
8105 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Waiting for receiving-thread:[first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1024] to die
8106 [Thread-25-worker-receiver-thread-0] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Receiving-thread:[first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1024] received shutdown notice
8107 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Shutdown receiving-thread: [first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1024]
8107 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down receive thread
8107 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Terminating messaging context
8107 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down executors
8108 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor __acker:[2 2]
8108 [Thread-10-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8109 [Thread-9-disruptor-executor[2 2]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8109 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor __acker:[2 2]
8109 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor appCount-Bolt:[4 4]
8110 [Thread-17-disruptor-executor[4 4]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8110 [Thread-18-appCount-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8112 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor appCount-Bolt:[4 4]
8113 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor mostCommon-Bolt:[6 6]
8113 [Thread-22-mostCommon-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8113 [Thread-21-disruptor-executor[6 6]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8114 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor mostCommon-Bolt:[6 6]
8114 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor __system:[-1 -1]
8115 [Thread-24-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8115 [Thread-23-disruptor-executor[-1 -1]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8116 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor __system:[-1 -1]
8116 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down executors
8116 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down transfer thread
8116 [Thread-26-disruptor-worker-transfer-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8116 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down transfer thread
8117 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down default resources
8118 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down default resources
8125 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Disconnecting from storm cluster state context
8126 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down worker first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390 11584c17-a7af-45a4-a2b3-d6285d13a730 1024
kill: 9312: No such process
8141 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Error when trying to kill 9312. Process is probably already dead.
kill: 9313: No such process
8149 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Error when trying to kill 9313. Process is probably already dead.
8153 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shut down 11584c17-a7af-45a4-a2b3-d6285d13a730:19989cf7-f5b8-4e88-8aef-7a752d948057
8153 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shutting down supervisor 11584c17-a7af-45a4-a2b3-d6285d13a730
8154 [Thread-3] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
8154 [Thread-4] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
8156 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shutting down 1d490baf-2811-4f90-92de-f1ca402ac4a6:bcea13bd-4bf8-4cd3-b4fc-fb65779c6527
8156 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.process-simulator - Killing process 6def0870-3372-4eaf-ab06-116fba6e1837
8156 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down worker first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390 1d490baf-2811-4f90-92de-f1ca402ac4a6 1027
8156 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down receive thread
8157 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Shutting down receiving-thread: [first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1027]
8157 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Waiting for receiving-thread:[first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1027] to die
8157 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Shutdown receiving-thread: [first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1027]
8157 [Thread-19-worker-receiver-thread-0] INFO  backtype.storm.messaging.loader - Receiving-thread:[first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390, 1027] received shutdown notice
8157 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down receive thread
8157 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Terminating messaging context
8157 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down executors
8157 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor actor-data:[3 3]
8157 [Thread-7-disruptor-executor[3 3]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8160 [Thread-8-actor-data] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8162 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor actor-data:[3 3]
8162 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor appID-Bolt:[5 5]
8162 [Thread-12-appID-Bolt] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8162 [Thread-11-disruptor-executor[5 5]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8163 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor appID-Bolt:[5 5]
8164 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor __system:[-1 -1]
8164 [Thread-14-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8164 [Thread-13-disruptor-executor[-1 -1]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8164 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor __system:[-1 -1]
8165 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shutting down executor __acker:[1 1]
8165 [Thread-16-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8165 [Thread-15-disruptor-executor[1 1]-send-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8167 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Shut down executor __acker:[1 1]
8167 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down executors
8167 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down transfer thread
8167 [Thread-20-disruptor-worker-transfer-queue] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Async loop interrupted!
8168 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down transfer thread
8169 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shutting down default resources
8169 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down default resources
8173 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Disconnecting from storm cluster state context
8175 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Shut down worker first_harvest_topology-1-1431981390 1d490baf-2811-4f90-92de-f1ca402ac4a6 1027
kill: 9310: No such process
8182 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Error when trying to kill 9310. Process is probably already dead.
kill: 9311: No such process
8189 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Error when trying to kill 9311. Process is probably already dead.
8191 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shut down 1d490baf-2811-4f90-92de-f1ca402ac4a6:bcea13bd-4bf8-4cd3-b4fc-fb65779c6527
8192 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Shutting down supervisor 1d490baf-2811-4f90-92de-f1ca402ac4a6
8193 [Thread-5] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
8194 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.event - Event manager interrupted
8197 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Shutting down in process zookeeper
8200 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Done shutting down in process zookeeper
8226 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path /var/folders/4x/pbrwf_8106j6spvvdp8mwm8m0000gn/T//ca74dbe3-44e4-426c-927e-fae30523823a
8232 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path /var/folders/4x/pbrwf_8106j6spvvdp8mwm8m0000gn/T//2c01662d-9970-4545-bd54-d573d107d86a
8234 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path /var/folders/4x/pbrwf_8106j6spvvdp8mwm8m0000gn/T//b7c396ef-27b4-455b-9387-1e8f91c24ca4
8244 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.testing - Deleting temporary path /var/folders/4x/pbrwf_8106j6spvvdp8mwm8m0000gn/T//80a6cec5-30fd-4ca5-b67b-32b4acf55915
```

Because of 30k character limit, I had to omit much of the beginning of the output, mainly the successfully connected statements

My CWD that contains my entire topology (just ask if you need to see any other files)

```
(test)Randalls-MacBook-Pro:first_harvest_topology randallbanks$ tree
.
├── README.md
├── _build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── META-INF
│   │       └── maven
│   │           └── first_harvest_topology
│   │               └── first_harvest_topology
│   │                   └── pom.properties
│   └── stale
│       └── extract-native.dependencies
├── _resources
│   └── resources
│       ├── bolts
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── appCount_Bolt.py
│       │   ├── getAppID_Bolt.py
│       │   └── tenMostCommon_Bolt.py
│       └── spouts
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── actorData.py
├── config.json
├── data
│   └── 405labs
│       └── reports
│           ├── drive
│           │   └── drive_2014-01-01_to_2015-02-17.macie.json
│           └── token
│               └── token_2014-01-01_to_2015-05-07.macie.json
├── fabfile.py
├── first_harvest_topology.txt
├── logs
│   ├── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_actor-data_3_9284.log
│   ├── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_actor-data_3_9310.log
│   ├── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_appCount-Bolt_4_9283.log
│   ├── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_appCount-Bolt_4_9312.log
│   ├── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_appID-Bolt_5_9286.log
│   ├── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_appID-Bolt_5_9311.log
│   ├── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_mostCommon-Bolt_6_9285.log
│   └── streamparse_first_harvest_topology_mostCommon-Bolt_6_9313.log
├── project.clj
├── src
│   ├── bolts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── appCount_Bolt.py
│   │   ├── getAppID_Bolt.py
│   │   └── tenMostCommon_Bolt.py
│   └── spouts
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── actorData.py
├── tasks.py
├── topologies
│   └── first_harvest_topology.clj
└── virtualenvs

22 directories, 31 files
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a kind of new at streamparse, like you. But I can see a few things that maybe could help.

If you are running with "sparse run" then you must have in your "virtualenvs" folder a file containing this:

```
streamparse # always required for streamparse projects
```

and you must name it as your topology with txt extension (in this case first_harvest_topology.txt).
I can see that you have the file, but not inside the virtualenvs folder.

Another issue could be, if you are only running "sparse run", that this command only runs for 5 seconds. Try with "sparse run -t x" where x is how many seconds you want to run the code. If you use "-t 0" your code will run until you kill it (you should try this)

You've probably solved your issue (this post is 2 months old) but it can help another person with a similar problem. Hope this helps